# Python Group by based on different values in rows

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame with the 3 columns:sequence, id, time

```
sequence= [4, 4, 5, 'safe', 'safe', 5, 'safe', 4, 'preferred', 'preferred', 'discarded', 'discarded']
```

I want to group the df by id and sequence by using groupby function and get an average time. I have the following code:

```
df.groupby(['id','sequence'])['time'].mean().reset_index(name='avg_time')
```

But the thing is I actually have 3 groups, not 6. The groups are: 4 or 5, preferred or discarded, safe.

How can I update the code to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a new column that assigns a sequence type to each item and then group by that:

```py
def sequence_filter(x):
    if x == 'safe':
        return x
    elif x in [4, 5]:
        return '4_5'
    else:
        return 'preferred_discarded'

df['sequence_type'] = df.sequence.apply(sequence_filter)
```

##### Output:

```py
     sequence        sequence_type
0           4                  4_5
1           4                  4_5
2           5                  4_5
3        safe                 safe
4        safe                 safe
5           5                  4_5
6        safe                 safe
7           4                  4_5
8   preferred  preferred_discarded
9   preferred  preferred_discarded
10  discarded  preferred_discarded
11  discarded  preferred_discarded
```

Then `df.groupby(['id','sequence_type'])['time'].mean().reset_index(name='avg_time')` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you need the original sequence columns, you can create a dictionary to map your values into their desired groups:

```
D = {'4':"4 or 5",'5':"4 or 5",
"preferred":"preferred or discarded",
"discarded":"preferred or discarded","safe":"safe"}
```

Then say your data frame is such:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
"id":[1,2,3]*4,
"sequence" : [4, 4, 5, 'safe', 'safe', 5, 'safe', 4, 'preferred', 
'preferred', 'discarded', 'discarded'],
"time":range(12)})
```

Replace the column first with the new group and do your groupby:

```
df.replace({"sequence":D}).groupby(['id','sequence'])['time'].mean()

id  sequence              
1   4                          0.0
    preferred or discarded     9.0
    safe                       4.5
2   4                          4.0
    preferred or discarded    10.0
    safe                       4.0
3   5                          3.5
    preferred or discarded     9.5
```